# PHP code aposthropy problem what does it mean ""

Tags: php

I cannot understand the section `$type = ''`;
The question is: 
what does `$type = '';` mean?, particularly apostrophes, 
This is the function which writes out the types of variables.

```
     <?php

     function what_type($variable)
     {
     $type = '';
     if (is_integer($variable)) $type .= 'integer, '; else
     if (is_float($variable)) $type .= 'float, '; else
     if (is_string($variable)) $type .= 'string, ';
     if (is_numeric($variable)) 
     $type .= "and is_numeric($variable) === true";
     echo $type.'<br />'; 
     }

     $a = 7;
     $b = 3.25;
     $c = 'some code';
     $d = '55';

    echo '$a the value of 7 is the type of '; what_type($a);
    echo '$b the value of 3.25 is the type of '; what_type($b);
    echo '$c the value of ' . "'some code'" . ' is the type of ';
    what_type($c);                                            
    echo '$d the value of ' . "'55'" . ' is the type of '; what_type($d);
    ?>
```

Comment: '' is __empty__ string.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: That line just initialized `$type` to an empty string. That way the code doesn't throw an error for the concatenation later.

Comment: Single quotes (what you call "apostrophes") are used to wrap a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

```
$type = '';
```

This simply initializes the variable `$type` to an empty string. This is not explicitly needed because PHP defaults undeclared variables to empty values. However, if you do not initialize the variable, and then later try to change it:

```
$type = $type . 'integer, ';
```

Or use it:

```
echo $type;
```

Then you'll get a warning from PHP that you're trying to change a variable that doesn't exist. Thus, setting the variable to an empty blank string is a common way to avoid that warning.

Answer (score 0):

here `$type = ''` is a default value for the `$type` variable.
In you example

```
if (is_integer($variable)) $type .= 'integer, '; else
if (is_float($variable)) $type .= 'float, '; else
if (is_string($variable)) $type .= 'string, ';
if (is_numeric($variable)) 
$type .= "oraz is_numeric($variable) === true";
```

You set `$type` variable only if at least one of four `if` will be true. 
For example if `$variable` is bool type you wont set `$type` variable and get undefined variable error that`s why you need to set some default value for variable to be sure that this variable will exist for sure.